# Log4net unable to write to event log, only creates the file

Tags: windows, log4net

On local machine log4net writes the event log, on server it only creates the file but it doesn't write on it.
It can't be permissions because it creates the file...

Any suggestion?

```xml
<configSections>
   <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationS``ectionHandler,log4net"/>
   <section name="activerecord" type="Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.Config.ActiveRecordSectionHandler, Castle.ActiveRecord"/>
</configSections>


<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <file value="C:\Logs\Services"/>
            <appendToFile value="true"/>
            <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
            <rollingStyle value="Composite"/>
            <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd.lo\g"/>
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="5"/>
            <maximumFileSize value="100MB"/>
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                    <conversionPattern value="%newline %date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline"/>
           </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
          <!-- priority value can be set to ALL|INFO|WARN|ERROR -->
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"/>
      </root>
</log4net>
```

EDIT: more information I can give you

on DEBUG MODE of LOG4NET it writes on server and I can see all DEBUG LOG

and finishes with these lines

```
log4net: Type = [3], r0 = [19700101.log], r1 = [19700102.log]  
log4net: curSizeRollBackups starts at [0]  
log4net: reated Appender [RollingLogFileAppender]  
log4net: Adding appender named [RollingLogFileAppender] to logger [root]  
log4net: Hierarchy Threshold []  
log4net: Shutdown called on Hierarchy [log4net-default-repository]
```

Comment: Post your log4net config file for starters.  File and Event Log permissions are not likely to be the same, so you cannot rule this out without more details.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you posted the wrong configuration, then you don't have any EventLogAppender.

Try adding that:

```xml
<log4net>
 <appender name="eventlog" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender">
  <param name="ApplicationName" value="yourappname" />
  <param name="LogName" value="yourlognameoneventlog" />
  <param name="Threshold" value="all" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n" />
  </layout>
 </appender>

 <root>
      <!-- priority value can be set to ALL|INFO|WARN|ERROR -->
  <level value="ALL"/>
  <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"/>
  <appender-ref ref="eventlog" />
 </root>
</log4net>
```

and change "ApplicationName" and "LogName" values according to your needs.

Comment: it was a problems of permissions, the user didn't had permissions to write to log!